# Smooth shading only works in viewport shading

Tags: shaders

*I'm still pretty new to blender (started a week ago), so there might be an obvious solution to my problem that I'm simply not aware of, but I'd still like to ask for help anyway.*

I was following blenderguru's anvil tutorial, and everything was going fine until the time came for **Normals baking**.

- I noticed the normals had choppy, flat shading in many areas, so to make sure everything was fine I re-did them, but the issue was still there.
- I noticed that the issue actualy affects the base, lower-res anvil model as well.

I tried recalculating normals, but as of right now everything fails and there is no difference between smooth and flat shading in render and material preview. (applying the subdivision doesn't change anything either

Smooth shading in viewport
[image: Smooth shading in viewport]

Flat and smooth shading look the same here and in render
[image: Flat and smooth shading look the same here and in render]

Comment: Can you highlight where the smooth shading is behaving different in the material preview view, other than that the material itself is different?

Comment: I can't get to my pc rn, but basically it shades the anvil (especially visible at the horn) as if I chose flat shading, which is not the case, as I want it to be shaded smoothly like in the first screenshot

Comment: So the second screenshot is also in object preview mode.  What's the difference between those two that caused the loss of smoothness? Because whatever that is is probably the source of the problem, since the horn is the same in the 2nd and 3rd shots

Comment: If you mean the difference between first and second shot, then the first one I chose smooth and in second I chose flat to show that the flat one looks the same as material preview with smooth. If you meant what the difference was between second and third shot then that's the problem, I have no idea because the only difference is the preview mode, since mat preview looks like flat shading regardless of the actual shading method that I choose

Comment: hello please share your file (upload and copy paste the URL): https://pasteall.org/blend/

Comment: Fastest solving would be moonboots suggestion ... from my side I would like to suggest - edit your Q - Delete middle screen that generates confusion and clarify if 3rd image is using baked Normal map (if so, edit image description). If the issue lays in missing smooth shading in your bake - edit the title as well. Thank you

Comment: I guess I worded my question a bit chaotically so I'll try to make it more clear.
I wanted to bake normals of an anvil model (not shown in the photos) which were getting weird choppy segments for no reason. This led me to discovering that the problem comes all the way from the original, low-res anvil model (shown in the photos). I noticed that it has to do with renderer (both cycles and eevee) ignoring smooth shading. I am trying to figure out why the render engines can't smooth shade my anvil, as that will also fix the issue of the normals that I want to bake from the high-detail anvil.

Comment: also here's the link https://pasteall.org/blend/caf854bcc60e401984d786701f006d98

Comment: You have to click Pack icon next to image name in properties (or File > External Data > Pack Resources to provide bake result ... anyway you cant plug Normal map texture directly to Normal socket you have to use Normal Map node in between (also texture should be set as Non-color (not sRGB) ... also you can't have pluged texture before bake due circular dependency. Also you should bake normal map as at least PNG (16-bit) or even better EXR (32-bit) since JPG support only 8-bit format that is not enough color info to provide smooth results.

Comment: Also there is not a reaso to bake "Selected to Active" ... Also at the moment your UVmap parts are too close to each other for given bake Output > Margin ... It means margin of one part is baked into another.

Comment: Ok but all you said doesn't really fix the issue that the renderer doesn't smooth render the model at all. I'm pretty sure that the normals I want to bake (btw the high res model that I want to use for baking isn't included in the file I sent because it was too big) wouldn't look okayish at least, if they were properly smooth rendered.

Comment: Okay nevermind, turns out that because I had a blank, full black texture hooked up to the "normal" part of the material on all of the anvils it broke the lighting, I removed it and now it works fine. I feel like an idiot rn but at least I'll learn to check my stuff better